# Optimize querysets calls when you need to get results separately for different attributes of a Model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Model Account that can have multiple attributes.

Based on attributes other queries are execute. To get an attribute I do a query:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    accounts_h = Account.objects.filter(is_home=True)
    accounts_i = Account.objects.filter(is_featured=True)
    accounts_t = Account.objects.filter(is_t=True)

    products_h = Product.objects.filter(account_id__in=accounts_h)
    products_i = Product.objects.filter(account_id__in=accounts_i)
    companies_t = Company.objects.filter(account_id__in=accounts_t)
```

The problem is that I have to do similar queries for multiple attributes(more than 6) on the Accounts, and other related Models which is not optimal.

How can I optimize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can optimize db queries like below. I've replace 3 queries of Account to 1 and 2 queries of Product to 1.

When we query to database it has to fetch the data into volatile memory and process it for each query. what I did is I fetched all results from db at once and processed. It saves the fetching time of data from db

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    accounts = Account.objects.filter(Q(is_home=True)| Q(is_featured=True)| Q(is_t=True))
    accounts_h = []
    accounts_i = []
    accounts_t = []
    for acc in accounts:
        if acc.is_home:
          accounts_h.append(acc.id)
        if acc.is_t:
          accounts_t.append(acc.id)
        if acc.is_i:
          accounts_i.append(acc.id)
    products = Product.objects.filter(account_id__in=accounts)
    products_h = filter(lambda obj : obj.id n accounts_h, products)
    products_i = filter(lambda obj : obj.id n accounts_i, products)
    companies_t = Company.objects.filter(account_id__in=accounts_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you want:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    products_h = Product.objects.filter(account__is_home=True)
    products_i = Product.objects.filter(account__is_featured=True)
    companies_t = Company.objects.filter(account__is_t=True)
```